# Malware from Android text?

Tags: malware, wifi, android, virus, ip

Lots of questions!

I clicked a scam USPS link on my phone while half asleep. The website loaded and a small window popped up immediately and I quickly backed out of my browser but briefly saw the site - it was obviously not trying to look like usps so I'm concerned it contained a virus or malware. (I don't have the exact url but the first part was atorensa dot com)

I installed and ran AVG on the phone right away (I didn't have antivirus on it before this) and it came up blank but I factory reset it just incase. I reset all my important passwords.

I figured everything was well after I reset my phone and went about my business scanning and printing tax documents, checking my accounts etc.

Then it occurred to me that I should probably be worried that my router/modem (combo) could've been affected as the phone was on the wifi along with a secondary phone, my computer, chromebook and printer.

My router is owned by my ISP and I am not able to do firmware updates on it but I did a factory reset on it as well albeit a few hours later. My printer only allows for a "semi-full" reset - whatever that means. My computer has Kaspersky and it came up blank - then I installed and ran malwarebytes and it came up with PUP.optional.Vosternan alerts.

I checked my emails for anything suspicious and a few of them were signed into from a different IP address. Between early Mar and when the risky click happened - I had one IP address #1. Then after the risky click I reset my router etc. It showed a new IP address. I tried factory resetting the router again but it still showed IP address #2. I called my internet provider and they use dynamic IP addresses. Maybe it is a coincidence that the IP changed during this time since I wasn't able to replicate the change with another reset?

Is my phone still potentially compromised?
Is there a way to scan my router/printer/chromebook for malware directly?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: AV solutions on Android aren't as useful, the best they could do is detect malware/potentially malicous/PUPs containing apps afaik.

Comment: I meant to use the word versatile in comparison to PC AV solutions.

Comment: "...I should probably be worried that my router/modem (combo) could've been affected as the phone was on the wifi..." Why should you probably be worried? What makes you think this is probable? You might as well be worried about a meteor landing on your head and/or being struck by lighting.

Comment: @Sir Muffington Is there anything else I can do to ensure my phone isn't compromised in some way? I can't find a local store that can do any extensive checks in to androids since I guess virus/malware isn't very common on android.

Comment: @hft I did google searches about viruses/malware on androids and one of the sites mentioned it was possible for a hack such as that to happen. But as you said, it seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @RiskyClickQs you could in theory take a snapshot/dd image of your android phone and forensically analyze it, but it's probably beyond your scope...

Comment: @Sir Muffington Lol accurate

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think about who would have the motivation to hack you.
Since you 'only' visited a malicious website, hacking your phone and router would require multiple [Zero-days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)). The use of zero-days mostly available to APTs, experienced cyber gangs (state sponsored hackers, large criminal organizations,...) and is mostly *NOT* used for mass exploitation, because every time you use a zero-day you increase the chance of losing your zero-day due to the fact that it could get discovered. As such, performing a full on 'hack' is not really done by sending random USPS links, this appears like a rather "regular" phishing attempt.

With dynamic IPs it is possible that you received a new IP-adress the moment you tried resetting your router. Some routers are programmed to do that or maybe the lease time ended just at that time.

I suggest using MFA where possible and the use of strong passwords/password manager.
You can also check on your router dashboard if all connected devices are known to you.

Complete network enumeration is very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will definitely follow your advice regarding passwords.